# Prevent JEST from running according to an environment variable

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to prevent JEST from running any tests, and show an error if an environment variable is missing.

I know that it's possible to do some setup in `setupFilesAfterEnv`, but I don't see how can I stop JEST there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach here is actually to check the environment variable before running the command itself (with bash or cmd or another js script).

For example, if you want to check 1 variable from the npm script, you can do the following:

```
// with bash
//package.json
"scripts": {
    "test": "[[ -z \"$MY_ENV\" ]] && echo \"MY_ENV NOT FOUND!\" || jest"
}

//with JS
//env-checker.js

if (!process.env.hasOwnProperty('MY_ENV')) {
    console.error('could not find MY_ENV!')
    process.exit(1)
}

//package.json
"scripts": {
    "test": "node env-checker.js && jest"
}
```

**Update:**
You can also exit the process from within `Jest`, but I'd say it's rather a hack because you also limit yourself with 1 failed test only.
Reference in Jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#bail-number-boolean

```
//in jest config
{
    "setupFiles": ["./env-checker.js"],
    "bail": 1
}
```

Comment: Yea, this is one of the obvious options, Thought that this might be possible within jest

Comment: @gilamran There is a way, however a hacky one. I added the update to my answer.